# React Autosuggest throwing error on clicking the suggestions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autosuggest

I am using React-autosuggest in my code but the issue i am facing is this that whenever i am clikcing any suggestion i am getting error that

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined

Here is my code

```
var subjectsToBeSearched= []

const getSuggestions = value => {
  const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
  const inputLength = inputValue.length;

  return inputLength === 0
    ? []
    :subjectsToBeSearched.filter(
        lang => lang.name.toLowerCase().slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue
      );
};
const getSuggestionValue = suggestion => suggestion.name;
`
const renderSuggestion = suggestion => <div>{suggestion.name}</div>;

export default class Searchbar extends Component {
  state = {
    language_id: "",
    subjects: [],
    value: "",
    suggestions: []
  };
  onChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    },()=>console.log(this.state.value));
  };
  onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: getSuggestions(value)
    });
  };
  onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: []
    });
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    let languageid = localStorage.getItem("language_id");
    var userdata = window.localStorage.getItem("userdata");

    if (languageid == null) {
      localStorage.setItem("language_id", 0);
    }
    this.setState({ language_id: languageid, userdata: JSON.parse(userdata) });
    this.getAllSubjects();
  }

  getAllSubjects = async () => {
    let details = {
      language_id: this.state.language_id
    };

    this.setState({
      response: fetch("http://18.221.47.207:3000/get_subjects", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "Cache-Control": "max-age=31536000"
        }
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
          this.setState(
            {
              subjects: responseJson
            },
            () => {
              let subjectsToBeFind = this.state.subjects.map(item => {
                return { id: item.subject_id, name: item.subject_name };
              });
              subjectsToBeSearched=subjectsToBeFind
            }
          );
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.setState({
            loading: false
          });
          swal("Warning!", "Check your network!", "warning");
          console.log(error);
        })
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { value, suggestions } = this.state;
    const inputProps = {
      value,
      onChange: this.onChange
    };

    return (
      <div className={`${styles.InputHeaderSearchDiv} `}>
        <Autosuggest 
           inputProps={inputProps}
          className={`${styles.InputHeaderSearch}`}
          suggestions={suggestions}
          onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
          onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
        //   alwaysRenderSuggestions={true} 
          getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionValue}
          renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
        />
        <div className={`${styles.SearchIcon}`}>
          <img src={SearchIcon} alt="search" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So when i click on any suggestion i just need to console and do some stuff but right away it throws error

Comment: As what the error message is saying, the `Autosuggest` callback in `onSuggestionsFetchRequested ` may return `undefined` under certain use operation.

Answer (score 3):

When you click a suggestion, the value of the "value" key in the inputProps is undefined thats the reason that you are getting a cannot trim error.

A workaround I did is add a props called "onSuggestionSelected" ( [Documentation for onSuggestionSelected found here](https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest#on-suggestion-selected-prop) ) and added a function that set the value of the "value" key in the inputProps to whatever value you want your input tag should have after the click event.

[THIS IS HOW MY AUTOSUGGEST LOOKSLIKE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AihiI.png)

[HERE IS MY FUNCTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKe5D.png)

Answer (score 2):

in my case simply setting value of inputProps to string did it

```
<Autosuggest
inputProps: {
value: whateverValue.toString()
```

Comment: This helped me figure out the problem, as it set the input text to `[object Object]`. Obviously I set the `inputProps` value to the object rather than the intended string property.